# How i make an element to be shown or not?

Tags: javascript

`anchorArrows` is an element that if I click the checkbox it must be shown and if it's not checked it must be hidden. The `classList` hidden and show are CSS classes with opacity 0 and 1

```js
    let q = document.getElementById("Q").value;
    let q2 = document.getElementById("q2").value;
    const anchorArrows = document.getElementById("anchor");
    
    if((chkQ.checked == true) && (chkQ2.checked == false)){

        anchorArrows.classList.add("show");
        anchorArrows.classList.remove("hidden");
        if(q > 0){
            flechas(0,"x");
        }else{
            flechas(180,"x");
        }
    }else{
        anchorArrows.classList.remove("show");
        anchorArrows.classList.add("hidden");
    }

    if((chkQ2.checked == true) && (chkQ.checked == false)){
        anchorArrows.classList.add("show");
        anchorArrows.classList.remove("hidden");
        if(q > 0){
            flechas(0,"y");
        }else{
            flechas(180,"y");
        }
    }else{
        anchorArrows.classList.remove("show");
        anchorArrows.classList.add("hidden");
    }
```

CSS:

```css
    .hidden{
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .show{
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant HTML. Even better would be a runnable stack snippet

Comment: Your code is incomplete - but `opacity:1` is the default state. You don't have to make a separate class for it. Just have one class for hiding  and apply it when you want to hide, remove it when you want to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use else if and one else. The issue you have is the first if can be true, but the second else will wipe away the class.

```
if (chkQ.checked && !chkQ2.checked) {
  anchorArrows.classList.add("show");
  anchorArrows.classList.remove("hidden");
  if (q > 0) {
    flechas(0, "x");
  } else {
    flechas(180, "x");
  }
} else if (chkQ2.checked && !chkQ.checked) {
  anchorArrows.classList.add("show");
  anchorArrows.classList.remove("hidden");
  if (q > 0) {
    flechas(0, "y");
  } else {
    flechas(180, "y");
  }
} else {
  anchorArrows.classList.remove("show");
  anchorArrows.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

And to get rid of repeated code

```
let isValid = false;

if ((!chkQ.checked && chkQ2.checked) || (chkQ.checked && !chkQ2.checked)) {
  isValid = true;
  const num = +q > 0 ? 0 : 180;
  const code = chkQ.checked ? "x" : "y";
  flechas(num, code);
} 

anchorArrows.classList.toggle("show", isValid);
anchorArrows.classList.toggle("hidden", !isValid);
```

Comment: That's actually insane, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't use classes to change opacity, as multiple variables can affect the outcome of it. Instead, I would put opacity in the original Id/Class in the CSS, and use .style.opacity to change it.

For Example:

```
CSS:
#box {
     opacity:1;
}

HTML:
<div id="box"></div>

Javascript:
document.getElementById('box').style.opacity = .5;
```

In your code, it would be `anchorArrows.style.opacity = 1;` for show, and `anchorArrows.style.opacity = 0;` for hidden.